# grab xml single value on mvc controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Please check the XML response bellow. I want a single value in my variable from this whole XML. The target value navigation is marked bellow.

```
XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Load(responseStream);

string totalListings = xdoc.Element("findItemsAdvancedResponse").Element("paginationOutput").Element("totalEntries").Value;
```

I already tried above code but this wont work. it says- 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'

> findItemsAdvancedResponse->paginationOutput->totalEntries-> "Value i
>   need"

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<findItemsAdvancedResponse 
  xmlns="http://www.ebay.com/marketplace/search/v1/services">
  <ack>Success</ack>
  <version>1.13.0</version>
  <timestamp>2017-10-29T18:51:05.655Z</timestamp>
  <searchResult count="2">
    <item>
      <itemId>232328214987</itemId>
      <title>BRAND NEW Apple iPhone 6 Plus 5.5" Display 16GB GSM UNLOCKED Smartphone</title>
      <globalId>EBAY-US</globalId>
      <subtitle>BRAND NEW PHONE &amp; ACCESSORIES + RETAIL BOX</subtitle>
      <primaryCategory>
        <categoryId>9355</categoryId>
        <categoryName>Cell Phones &amp; Smartphones</categoryName>
      </primaryCategory>
      <galleryURL>http://thumbs4.ebaystatic.com/pict/232328214987404000000002_1.jpg</galleryURL>
      <viewItemURL>http://www.ebay.com/itm/BRAND-NEW-Apple-iPhone-6-Plus-5-5-Display-16GB-GSM-UNLOCKED-Smartphone-/232328214987?var=531582721516&amp;vti=</viewItemURL>
      <paymentMethod>PayPal</paymentMethod>
      <autoPay>true</autoPay>
      <postalCode>20879</postalCode>
      <location>Gaithersburg,MD,USA</location>
      <country>US</country>
      <sellerInfo>
        <sellerUserName>buyspry</sellerUserName>
        <feedbackScore>141448</feedbackScore>
        <positiveFeedbackPercent>98.5</positiveFeedbackPercent>
        <feedbackRatingStar>RedShooting</feedbackRatingStar>
        <topRatedSeller>true</topRatedSeller>
      </sellerInfo>
      <shippingInfo>
        <shippingServiceCost currencyId="USD">0.0</shippingServiceCost>
        <shippingType>Free</shippingType>
        <shipToLocations>Worldwide</shipToLocations>
        <expeditedShipping>true</expeditedShipping>
        <oneDayShippingAvailable>true</oneDayShippingAvailable>
        <handlingTime>1</handlingTime>
      </shippingInfo>
      <sellingStatus>
        <currentPrice currencyId="USD">329.99</currentPrice>
        <convertedCurrentPrice currencyId="USD">329.99</convertedCurrentPrice>
        <sellingState>Active</sellingState>
        <timeLeft>P6DT2H48M24S</timeLeft>
      </sellingStatus>
      <listingInfo>
        <bestOfferEnabled>false</bestOfferEnabled>
        <buyItNowAvailable>false</buyItNowAvailable>
        <startTime>2017-05-08T21:39:29.000Z</startTime>
        <endTime>2017-11-04T21:39:29.000Z</endTime>
        <listingType>FixedPrice</listingType>
        <gift>false</gift>
        <watchCount>2518</watchCount>
      </listingInfo>
      <returnsAccepted>true</returnsAccepted>
      <condition>
        <conditionId>1000</conditionId>
        <conditionDisplayName>New</conditionDisplayName>
      </condition>
      <isMultiVariationListing>true</isMultiVariationListing>
      <topRatedListing>true</topRatedListing>
    </item>
    <item>
      <itemId>332182393939</itemId>
      <title>Apple iPhone 6 (Factory Unlocked) AT&amp;T Verizon T-Mobile Gray Gold Silver $20 OFF</title>
      <globalId>EBAY-US</globalId>
      <subtitle>Top US Seller | $20 OFF INSTANTLY| Warranty | Case&amp;SP</subtitle>
      <primaryCategory>
        <categoryId>9355</categoryId>
        <categoryName>Cell Phones &amp; Smartphones</categoryName>
      </primaryCategory>
      <galleryURL>http://thumbs4.ebaystatic.com/pict/332182393939404000000003_3.jpg</galleryURL>
      <viewItemURL>http://www.ebay.com/itm/Apple-iPhone-6-Factory-Unlocked-AT-T-Verizon-T-Mobile-Gray-Gold-Silver-20-OFF-/332182393939?var=541215921735&amp;vti=</viewItemURL>
      <paymentMethod>PayPal</paymentMethod>
      <autoPay>true</autoPay>
      <location>USA</location>
      <country>US</country>
      <sellerInfo>
        <sellerUserName>cocosprinkles</sellerUserName>
        <feedbackScore>22252</feedbackScore>
        <positiveFeedbackPercent>99.6</positiveFeedbackPercent>
        <feedbackRatingStar>YellowShooting</feedbackRatingStar>
        <topRatedSeller>true</topRatedSeller>
      </sellerInfo>
      <shippingInfo>
        <shippingServiceCost currencyId="USD">0.0</shippingServiceCost>
        <shippingType>Free</shippingType>
        <shipToLocations>Worldwide</shipToLocations>
        <expeditedShipping>true</expeditedShipping>
        <oneDayShippingAvailable>false</oneDayShippingAvailable>
        <handlingTime>1</handlingTime>
      </shippingInfo>
      <sellingStatus>
        <currentPrice currencyId="USD">319.99</currentPrice>
        <convertedCurrentPrice currencyId="USD">319.99</convertedCurrentPrice>
        <sellingState>Active</sellingState>
        <timeLeft>P10DT21H5M41S</timeLeft>
      </sellingStatus>
      <listingInfo>
        <bestOfferEnabled>false</bestOfferEnabled>
        <buyItNowAvailable>false</buyItNowAvailable>
        <startTime>2017-04-13T15:56:46.000Z</startTime>
        <endTime>2017-11-09T15:56:46.000Z</endTime>
        <listingType>StoreInventory</listingType>
        <gift>false</gift>
        <watchCount>90</watchCount>
      </listingInfo>
      <returnsAccepted>true</returnsAccepted>
      <galleryPlusPictureURL>http://galleryplus.ebayimg.com/ws/web/332182393939_1_3_1_00000003.jpg</galleryPlusPictureURL>
      <condition>
        <conditionId>2000</conditionId>
        <conditionDisplayName>Manufacturer refurbished</conditionDisplayName>
      </condition>
      <isMultiVariationListing>true</isMultiVariationListing>
      <topRatedListing>true</topRatedListing>
    </item>
  </searchResult>
  <paginationOutput>
    <pageNumber>1</pageNumber>
    <entriesPerPage>2</entriesPerPage>
    <totalPages>47873</totalPages>
    <totalEntries>95746</totalEntries>
  </paginationOutput>
  <itemSearchURL>http://www.ebay.com/sch/9355/i.html?fsaspfilter=Brand%3DApple&amp;fscurrency=USD&amp;Brand%255Cu0007=Apple&amp;aspectrequest=1&amp;_ddo=1&amp;_ipg=2&amp;_mPrRngCbx=1&amp;_os=S%7CD&amp;_pgn=1&amp;_udhi=500&amp;_udlo=50</itemSearchURL>
</findItemsAdvancedResponse>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you are getting the exception is, `xdoc.Element("findItemsAdvancedResponse")` is returning `NULL` and you are trying to call another method on NULL, hence getting the typical null reference exception,***"Object reference not set to an instance of an object***".

The reason you are getting null is because, your XML has namespace, So when you access the XML element, you should use the namespace along with the element name you are looking for.

This should work.

```
var path = Server.MapPath("~/Content/YourXmlFile.xml");
var xdoc = XDocument.Load(path);

XNamespace ns = "http://www.ebay.com/marketplace/search/v1/services";

var totalEntries = xdoc?.Element(ns + "findItemsAdvancedResponse")
                  ?.Element(ns + "paginationOutput")?.Element(ns + "totalEntries")?.Value;
```

If you are using `XElement`, you can skip the outer xml element(`findItemsAdvancedResponse`) and start looking from the next level.

```
var path = Server.MapPath("~/Content/YourXmlFile.xml");
var xdoc = XElement.Load(path);

XNamespace ns = "http://www.ebay.com/marketplace/search/v1/services";

var totalEntries = xdoc?.Element(ns + "paginationOutput")?.
                                                   Element(ns + "totalEntries")?.Value;
```

Comment: why aw need to +? i dont have this aw on my code. i am getting response of html in xdoc  var

Comment: The `?` is C# 6 conditional null check operator. Synactical sugar of a null check on each element. In this case, If `xdoc` is null , the value of `totalEntries` will be null, else it checks `xdoc.Element(aw + "paginationOutput")` and if it is not null, then continue checking the next method call.

Comment: i meant why i need to add the url with variable "aw"?

Comment: Sorry ! I misread the comment. The answer for that question is , your XML has namespace, So when you access the XML element, you should use the Element method with namespace.

Comment: ah bro, how can i use it with my current code condition?